# What does UINT32_MAX mean?

Tags: objective-c

I seen UINT32_MAX in multiple languages, specifically in Objective-C, but what is it?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Do you know what a uint32 is?

Comment: @Thomas Why, yes. I thought it was the maximum number of an unsigned 32 bit integer, but the context of where I saw it confused me. It add 1 to UINT32_MAX for some reason.

Comment: If you are using x-code command+click the UINT32_MAX. It will automatically go to page that was declared.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is the maximum number that you can store within an unsigned 32 bit integer.

```
#define UINT32_MAX   (4294967295U)
```

Answer (score 0):

It is the maximum number that can be stored in an unsigned 32 bit integer i.e. 0xffffffff